# MarkLogic Samplestack installation issue (Execution failed for task ':dbTeardown')

Tags: marklogic

I'm trying to install [Samplestack application](https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-samplestack) for ML8.02 on OS X 10.10.3.

Following the instructions, everything goes well until the `gulp once --browser=chrome` step. This generates an Execution failed for task ':dbTeardown' error, leading to a "The Samplestack environment may not be properly configured." message.

According to the installation manual, this step needs to be called from the "local Samplestack repository root directory". Is this different from the "marklogic-samplestack directory" in previous steps? If so, where should I look?

Not knowing what to do, I used the marklogic-samplestack-master (root from downloaded zip) and got the following console error message. Any advice how to solve this?

```
[16:55:06] Warning: gulp version mismatch:
[16:55:06] Global gulp is 3.9.0
[16:55:06] Local gulp is 3.8.11
[16:55:07] Using gulpfile ~/Downloads/marklogic-samplestack-master/gulpfile.js
[16:55:07] Starting 'once'...
[16:55:08] Starting 'clean'...
[16:55:08] Starting 'middle-tier-start'...
reconfiguring database, starting app server

./gradlew dbInit --no-daemon
[16:55:08] Finished 'clean' after 189 ms
[16:55:08] Starting 'bower-files'...
[16:55:09] Finished 'bower-files' after 440 ms
[16:55:09] Starting 'build'...
.[16:55:10] processing files
...[16:55:13] saw 221 files
....[16:55:13] Finished 'build' after 4.29 s
(many dots)
./gradlew dbTeardown --no-daemon
...........................................
:
..
FAILURE:
Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dbTeardown'.
>
Failed Teardown.  Check environment before proceeding.

* Try:
Run with
--stacktrace
option to get the stack trace. Run with --info
or        
--debug
option to get more log output..... 
[16:58:47] detected middle tier started
preparations complete
[16:58:47] 'middle-tier-start' errored after 3.63 min
[16:58:47] Error: EXIT CODE: 1
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/matthijs/Downloads/marklogic-samplestack-master/shared/js/dev-tasks/e2e/middleTierJava.js:53:17)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)

Error(s) occurred.
The Samplestack environment may not be properly configured.
[16:58:47] 'once' errored after 3.65 min
[16:58:47] Error: 1
    at formatError             
(/Users/matthijs/.node/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:169:10)
at Gulp.<anonymous> 
(/Users/matthijs/.node/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:195:15)
at Gulp.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (/Users/matthijs/Downloads/marklogic-samplestack-master/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:264:8)
at /Users/matthijs/Downloads/marklogic-samplestack-master/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:275:23
at finish (/Users/matthijs/Downloads/marklogic-samplestack-master/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:21:8)
at cb (/Users/matthijs/Downloads/marklogic-samplestack-    master/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:29:3)
at ChildProcess.onDone (/Users/matthijs/Downloads/marklogic-samplestack-master/shared/js/dev-tasks/tasks/once.js:38:20)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:117:20)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
```

Comment: Hello, there's not quite enough to go on here for a good answer.  There are a lot of things that could be happening in your environment to prevent a clean teardown.  Have you taken a look at the administration GUI on port 8001?  A look there will give you an idea of how your application servers/databases/forests are set up and what you might need to do to clean things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run into the same problem by following the guide and trying to skip 
[Set up the Java middle tier and database tier with gradle](https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-samplestack/blob/master/appserver/java-spring/README.md#quickstart) step in order to configure Node.js-based middle tire only.

It can be seen from the log that *gradle* is used during [First-Time Setup](https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-samplestack/blob/master/README-JavaScript.md#first-time-setup-of-samplestack-and-initial-test) step. So I followed the first link above and as far as the second paragraph it goes

> If you have already secured MarkLogic, you need to update gradle.properties with the admin credentials you used during the install and setup process.

Hope it helps.